# ¿Cómo funcionan las aplicaciones de redes sociales?

Tags: android, android-studio, ios, aplicación-web, app

**Es solo una pregunta teórica.**
Tanto instagram como twitter, tumblr, etc, tienen una web y apps en android e IOS. ¿Son esas aplicaciones solo un "portal" a la web o están "creadas de 0" en sus respectivos lenguajes?
No tengo mucha idea sobre el tema y no encuentro mucho en internet.

Gracias.

Comment: A ciencia cierta solo lo saben las compañias, pero podrian ser tanto aplicaciones nativas como aplicaciones hibridas. Las primeras son aprlicaciones desarrolladas en sus respectivos lenguages (Apple Swift / Android JAVA), mientras que las segundas son aplicaciones creadas para WEB a las que se les coloca en un shell de aplicación nativa.

Comment: De todas formas, lo mas seguro es que al ser aplicaciones de empresas importantes sean nativas, y cada empresa tendra un equipo para cada sistema operativo.

Comment: Muchas gracias.